# symmetric polynomial recursion to solve the system, $x^5+y^5=33$, $x+y=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, substitution, symmetric-polynomials

I was just reading on symmetric polynomials and was given the system of equations$$x^5+y^5=33 \text{ , } x+y=3$$

In the text they said to denote $\sigma_1=x+y$ and $\sigma_2=xy$, and to use recursion.  I understand how the formula below works
$$S_5=x^5+y^5=\sigma_1 S_4-\sigma_2 S_3$$

But doing the recursion takes a long time.  Is there a shorter way to do the recursion to solve this specific problem?

Thanks

Comment: what is $x^2 + y^2 \; $ in terms of $\sigma_2 \; ?$

Comment: Not sure I could get it just in terms of $\sigma_2$, but I know that $x^2+y^2=(\sigma_1)^2-2\sigma_2$

Comment: and $\sigma_1 = 3$

Comment: oh, yes.  so $x^2+y^2=9-2\sigma_2$

Comment: so, what is $x^3 + y^3 \; ?$

Comment: let me add an explicit hint, $xy^2 + x^2 y = xy(x+y)$

Comment: So the method is to consider the terms inside of $x^5$ and $y^5$ in the expansion of $(x+y)^5$?  Since the polynomial is reciprocal, for the expansion of $(x^5+y^5)$ should I group those terms with the same coefficients. so I'd get $x^5+y^5=(x+y)^5-5xy(x^3+y^3)-10xy(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: That would work, if you got $x^3 + y^3 \; .$ In the end, you have an expression in $\sigma_2$ that you can set equal to $33.$

Comment: Once you have that, you can finally find $(x-y)^2$

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Yes, the hint is about continuing with that recursion (Newton's identities). Always replacing $\sigma_1$ with $3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x+y=3=a$, $xy=b$, $x^5+y^5=33=c$.

\begin{align} 
x^5+y^5&=(x+y)(x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4)
\\
c&=
a(x^4+y^4-x^2xy+(xy)^2-xyy^2)
\\
c&=
x^4+y^4-b(x^2+y^2)+b^2
,\\
x^4+y^4&=(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2=(x^2+y^2)^2-2b^2
,\\
c&=
a((x^2+y^2)^2-2b^2-b(x^2+y^2)+b^2)
=
a(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2-b)-b^2)
,\\
x^2+y^2&=(x+y)^2-2xy=a^2-2b
,\\
c&=
a(a^2-2b)(a^2-2b-b)-ab^2
,
\end{align}

thus we have a quadratic equation in terms of $b$:

\begin{align} 
5ab^2-5a^3b-c+a^5&=0
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
b&=\frac{(5a^3\pm\sqrt{5a^6+20ac}}{10a}
,\\
b_1&=2
,\\
b_2&=7
.
\end{align}

So, we need to consider two cases: $xy=2$ and $xy=7$.
In both cases we also have $x+y=3$.

Case 1 $xy=2$.

The quadratic equation with roots $x,y$ is
\begin{align} 
t^2-3t+2&=0
,\\
x,y&=1,2
.
\end{align}

Indeed, $1^5+2^5=33$, $1+2=3$, 
so in Case 1 we have two real solutions, $x=1,y=2$ and $x=2,y=1$.

Case 2 $xy=7$.

The quadratic equation with roots $x,y$ is
\begin{align} 
t^2-3t+7&=0
,\\
x,y&=\tfrac32\pm\tfrac{\sqrt{19}}2\cdot i
,
\end{align}

so in Case 2 we have 
two complex conjugate solutions, 
\begin{align} 
x&=\tfrac32+\tfrac{\sqrt{19}}2\cdot i
,\\
y&=\tfrac32-\tfrac{\sqrt{19}}2\cdot i
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align} 
x&=\tfrac32-\tfrac{\sqrt{19}}2\cdot i
,\\
y&=\tfrac32+\tfrac{\sqrt{19}}2\cdot i 
.
\end{align}

Comment: But the OP wants a 'shorter way'...

Comment: @Szeto: Well, technically, it can be considered somewhat shorter,
since $S_3$ is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Also, we can use the homogenization.

Let $y=tx$.

Thus, $$t^5+1=\frac{33(t+1)^5}{243}$$ or
$$(t+1)(2t-1)(t-2)(7t^2+5t+7)=0$$ and the rest is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a shorter way to do the recursion to solve this specific problem?`

If you don't insist on recursion, the shorter way *in this case*  is arguably the most direct one - just solve the system by eliminating one of the variables, then factoring with the rational root theorem:

$$
\begin{align}
0 = x^5 + y^5 - 33 &= x^5+(3-x)^5-33 \\
 &= 15 (x^4 - 6 x^3 + 18 x^2 - 27 x + 14) \\
 &= 15 (x - 1) (x - 2) (x^2 - 3 x + 7)
\end{align}
$$